# Probability to choose $lists$ that cover $S$ $k$-times; with my algorithm.

Tags: probability-distributions, algorithms

1. The lists are treated as sets of 3.
2. The lists only contain integers.
3. Ignore lists that have integers that do not cover $S$
4. Lists are sorted from smallest to largest values (eg $[1,2,3]$ not $[3,2,1]$)
5. Only one permutation of a list is allowed. (eg. my algorithm deletes all orderings of $[1,2,3]$, but only leaves $[1,2,3]$)
6. We are given two inputs |s| and $c$ (lists of "3-lists")
7. $k$-times = mod `(length(s)/3)-1`
8. Edit: No repeating lists

### Sort all "*3-lists*" in this order.

Input = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[2,8,9],[3,4,6],[4,5,7],[1,2,4]

All [1,2,$i$]'s are grouped next to each other. So are the [4,5,$i$]'s, and so on.

Sorted

[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[4,5,6],[4,5,7],[2,8,9],[3,4,6]

Sampling Algorithm

```
stop = 0
skip_item = 0

n = length(S)
b = 241
steps = n*(b)*((n*(b))-1)*((n*(b))-2)//6


while stop <= steps:

    # Shuffling c randomly

    shuffle()
    skip_item = skip_item + 1
    stop = stop + 1

    # skip_item helps
    # select correct list.
    # (eg. 3Set-Cover solution uses [4,5,6] not [4,5,7])
    # Will reset variables and try again...


    if skip_item > length(c):
        covered_elements = set()
        skip_item = 0
        sort_3Lists()
        # ^^Sorting 3-lists with [1,2, i]'s and so on. ^^
        
    # The heart of the algorithm.        
    # Keep c[0]
    # and append to
    # end of list
    # delete c[0]
    # to push >>
    # in list.
 
    c.append(c[0])
    del [c[0]]
    solution = []
    covered_elements = set()
    
    for l in c:
        if not any(v in covered_elements for v in l):
            solution.append(l)
            covered_elements.update(l)

    if length(solution) >= (length(s)//3)-1:
        OUTPUT('Solution Found',solution)
        HALT
```

### Two Questions

What is the worst-case probability that my algorithm fails to find a $k$ Three-Cover for $S$?

What is the average-case probability that my algorithm finds a $k$ Three-Cover for $S$?

Comment: I am a computer/programming hobbyist who has limited math-skills that are not beyond College-Algebra. Please be patient with me.

Comment: I am assuming that our input for S is in the sequence of (1, K). For the most part.